# Pass the Message project problem with setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making beginner javascript pass the message project I'm having a problem with this: If no input is submitted, an alert should show (using the ‘show' class in the CSS file) in the “Last Message Delivered” section and then disappear after **2 second**. I don't know setTimeout and setInterval methods really good and how to break them but if someone could help.

```js
const adder = document.getElementById('message-form')
const cont = document.querySelector('.boxer')
const feeder = document.querySelector('.feedback')
let counter = 0;


adder.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let texto = adder.oop.value
  if (texto.length) {

    html = `
    <div class="boxerr">
    <h5 class="p-2 alert alert-danger my-3 text-capitalize feedback">please enter a value to pass</h5>
    <h4 class="text-capitalize my-3">last message delivered</h4>
    <h4 class="message-content text-uppercase">${texto}</h4>
  </div>
    `
    cont.innerHTML += html
    adder.reset()
  } else {

    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      counter++
      feeder.classList.toggle('show')
      if (counter === 2) {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --lightBlue: #95b8d1;
  --mainwhite: #f5f5f5;
  --mainBlack: #333333;
}

.max-height {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background: var(--lightBlue);
}

.message-container {
  background: var(--mainwhite);
}

.message-content {
  color: var(--lightBlue);
}

#submitBtn {
  background: var(--lightBlue);
  color: var(--mainwhite);
}

#submitBtn:hover {
  color: var(--lightBlue);
  color: var(--mainBlack);
}

.feedback {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row max-height align-items-center">
    <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-8 message-container text-center p-3">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize">A messge you would like to pass</h4>
      <form id="message-form">
        <input type="text" name="oop" id="message" class="w-100 my-3 p-2">
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-lg">
      </form>
      <div class="boxer">
        <div class="boxerr">
          <h5 class="p-2 alert alert-danger my-3 text-capitalize feedback">please enter a value to pass</h5>
          <h4 class="text-capitalize my-3">last message delivered</h4>
          <h4 class="message-content text-uppercase">hello world</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in the `else` block:

```js
feeder.classList.add("show");
setTimeout(() => feeder.classList.remove("show"), 2000);
```

This code will add the `show` class to the `.feedback` element and after `2000` milliseconds *(i.e. 2 seconds as `1000ms = 1s`)* the `show` class will be removed from the `.feedback` element.

---

**Complete Code:**

```js
const adder = document.getElementById('message-form')
const cont = document.querySelector('.boxer')
const feeder = document.querySelector('.feedback')
let counter = 0;


adder.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let texto = adder.oop.value
  if (texto.length) {

    html = `
    <div class="boxerr">
    <h4 class="text-capitalize my-3">last message delivered</h4>
    <h4 class="message-content text-uppercase">${texto}</h4>
  </div>
    `
    cont.innerHTML += html
    adder.reset()
  } else {
    feeder.classList.add("show");
    setTimeout(() => feeder.classList.remove("show"), 2000);
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --lightBlue: #95b8d1;
  --mainwhite: #f5f5f5;
  --mainBlack: #333333;
}

.max-height {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background: var(--lightBlue);
}

.message-container {
  background: var(--mainwhite);
}

.message-content {
  color: var(--lightBlue);
}

#submitBtn {
  background: var(--lightBlue);
  color: var(--mainwhite);
}

#submitBtn:hover {
  color: var(--lightBlue);
  color: var(--mainBlack);
}

.feedback {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row max-height align-items-center">
    <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-8 message-container text-center p-3">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize">A messge you would like to pass</h4>
      <form id="message-form">
        <input type="text" name="oop" id="message" class="w-100 my-3 p-2">
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-lg">
      </form>
      <h5 class="p-2 alert alert-danger my-3 text-capitalize feedback">please enter a value to pass</h5>
      <div class="boxer">
        <div class="boxerr">
          <h4 class="text-capitalize my-3">last message delivered</h4>
          <h4 class="message-content text-uppercase">hello world</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thanks and also one more problem this message appears only once when i click empy bar it doesnt appear after i add some messages only in the beggining when nothing is added  what problem could it be ?

Comment: @dortax Oh, that is because you are making a `.feedback` element with each `.boxerr`, which you don't have to do. I am updating the code above to fix it.